# Setting a parameter to allow Null

Tags: reporting-services

I have added a parameter @ConstitID to a SSRS report and when selecting "allow null" I do not get any results unless I uncheck null and enter an integer.

I have tried this code in the Where Clause but it's not working. Why does it not use `NULL` appropriately?

```
WHERE
  (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
  AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date
     BETWEEN @TransactionDateStart AND @TransactionDateEnd)
  AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id = @ConstitID)
  OR (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id = NULL)
```

Comment: The last part of your query: `(p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id = NULL)` will always be false, but it's not directly related to your question. (Just pointing out a likely bug.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= NULL` in SQL will return false. You need to use `IS NULL`, so you'll need a second check of your parameter:

```
WHERE
 (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
 AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date
    BETWEEN @TransactionDateStart AND @TransactionDateEnd)
 AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id = @ConstitID
    OR @ConstitID IS NULL)
 OR (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I also had to select the parameter in SSRS and check Allow Null so that the Null option was available when rendering the report. Thank you